# Apache redirect rule for the same url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to write a `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to the following.

If someone tries to access forex.com or forexample.com they should both redirect to

```
forexample.com/abcd/xyz/
```

The below rewrite condition works for forex.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forex\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [R,NE]
```

But when I add another rule like below it goes to a redirect loop

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forexample\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [R,NE]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works because `forex.com` and `forexample.com` are different domains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forex\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [R,NE]
```

But in the second case, I believe the issue is that the rule as you have set will redirect anything on `https://forexample.com/` to `https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/` even if it is already in `https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forexample\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [R,NE]
```

So do a check for the `REQUEST_URI` not being `abcd/xyz/` and you should be good to go:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forexample\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(abcd/xyz/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [L,R,NE]
```

But then looking this over, the first `HTTP_HOST` rule makes little sense. Perhaps you want it to just be this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(abcd/xyz/.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://forexample.com/abcd/xyz/ [L,R,NE]
```

A good way to debug stuff like this is to use `curl -I` from the command line. That command will show you the exact HTTP headers you getting based on a rule or request. So use it like this; using my MAMP test environment for an example:

```
curl -I http://localhost:8888
```

And the output for me would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 28 Jun 2014 02:19:39 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10
Location: http://localhost:8888/abcd/xyz/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Note the `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` which means it’s a temporary redirect and the `Location: http://localhost:8888/abcd/xyz/` which indicates where the rule is rewriting the call to `http://localhost:8888` as.

Comment: If I use it like this
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forexample\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /abcd/xyz/ [R,NE]

It is forcing the port number that means it is redirecting to forexample:81/abcd/xyz which is page not avaialable

Comment: The above solution is not working any other suggestions please. I am getting a broken page with REQUEST_URI